# re-express a matrix product

Tags: matrices

\begin{array}
%\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{12} \\
    a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix}
=(a_{ij})(b_{ij})
\end{array}
Can anybody help me in separating $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$? In other words, what will be the two matrices (in multiplication) of order 2 by 2 each but one contain only $a_{ij}$ and other contain only $b_{ij}$ ?

Your help will be appreciated.

PS: None of $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are zero.

Comment: Setting all $a_{ij}$ values to $0$ is one solution.

Comment: From your wording I'm presuming that you want a decomposition that works in general. Why do you think it's possible to do so?

Comment: @epimorphic please educate me about it. I have no idea.

Comment: @epimorphic mathematically I can't justify but it is my expectation if it happens matrices looks simple.

Answer (score 2):

I am not totally sure if that is what you are asking since your notation is a little confusing; see that the result of the multiplication above is:

\begin{array}
%\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{12} \\
    a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11}b_{11} + a_{21}b_{21} &&  a_{12}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22}  \\
    a_{11}b_{11} + a_{21}b_{21} &&  a_{12}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} 
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}

If you want two matrices $2\times 2$, the first one with only $a_{ij}$ terms and the second with only $b_{ij}$ terms, then the first row and column respectively should be:

\begin{array}
%\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{21} & a_{11} \\
    ... & ...
  \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
    b_{21} & ... \\
    b_{11} & ...
  \end{pmatrix} \text{or}  
\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{21} \\
    ... & ...
  \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
    b_{11} & ... \\
    b_{21} & ...
  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{array}

Take the second case for example. Then the second row of $A$ must be, again

\begin{array}
%\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{21} \\
    a_{11} & a_{21}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    b_{11} & ... \\
    b_{21} & ...
  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{array}

And that conflicts with the fact that you need the $a_{12}, a_{22}$ somehwere. Same would happen if you pick the first case.

In conclusion, they cannot be separated the way you suggest